# "Puffin" as a verb

Tags: verbs

I read the lyrics of "Wasting time" from Kid Rock and it says:

Puffin the Winston, drinkin' a four-oh

What is the relation between Puffin and cigarettes?
And by the way, what drink is four-oh? Four roses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably thinking he was talking about the Puffin bird but it should have been spelled Puffin' or Puffing a cigarette (just as drinking was spelled drinkin'). It just means blowing out smoke.
A Four-O is usually a 40oz malt liquor.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a shortened version of "puffing," which is another way of saying smoking, since cigarettes make puffs of smoke.

Comment: BTW - as @Michael Sapp points out, it should probably be spelled out as `Puffin'`. A `Winston`, by the way is a __type__ of cigarette, at least in the United States, hence the association with cigarettes (for those who aren't familiar with this brand).